# Centralizar elemento nav

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Não estou conseguindo centralizar o elemento `<nav>`

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Responsive</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Responsive</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Responsive</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu {position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%;}
.menu ul {font-size: 15px; margin: 0 auto; }
.menu ul li {display: inline; }
.menu ul li a {margin: 0 auto;}
```

**Imagem:**
[image: nav]

Comment: Podes colocar o teu código?

Comment: Favor postar html e css para ajuda

Comment: Tenta também explicar melhor a questão, o que fizeste e qual está a ser o problema.

Comment: Editei o post com o meu código.

Comment: Consegues por uma imagem do teu nav?

Comment: @JorgeB. editei o posto com a imagem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Um simples  `text-align:center;` no seletor `.menu ul` deve resolver.

Então o CSS ficaria assim:

```
.menu {position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%;}
/* ↓ eu só subistitui o margin por text-align:center na linha abaixo ↓ */
.menu ul {font-size: 15px; text-align:center; }
.menu ul li {display: inline; }
.menu ul li a {margin: 0 auto;}
```

Exemplo:

#### [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/h6UVS/)

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou!

Comment: Mais rápido que eu, ein! Haha.

Comment: Valeu @GuilhermeOderdenge , estava vendo seu perfil e a URL do seu site está com um erro de digitação (```.cmo``` ao inves de ```.com```), só um toque. :)